# Jqgrid data not showing in table, but the data is coming via URL in the console, but it is now showing up in the table

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, codeigniter-3

[image]

I have been trying to setup jqgrid in a new project, everything works, but the data doesn't show up, what I mean by everything works is that, the data which I am fetching via backend, it is showing up in the console, and it is also showing in the pagination also.

Please check the link below: you can check the source code too.

http://globalaskit.com/dev/hms/manageCountry

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid is ok an your data is in the grid, but it is not displayed. The problem you have is in these grid settings:

```
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            ...
            height: $('.content-wrap').height() - 120,
            width: $('.content-wrap').width() - 20,
            ...
     });
```

In your case the height is 0, and the data is hidden.
The reason for this is that this element has height 0 when the grid is created or was hidden when the grid is created (since the request to the server is delayed).

To resolve the problem set a certain height in the grid settings.

If you really want the grids to expand to this height use the method to set the grid height after the grid is created. See docs.

Comment: Thank you so much... I didn't check the height before, now its all good.